# Trying to add a delete button in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I was trying to add a delete button to the list element but it was not adding. Now I created the Delete button using forEach loop but now the problem is the delete button is added only to the existing list only whenever I add a new item in the list the list gets added but the delete button is not created.

```
function createButton(lis) {
const list = document.querySelectorAll("li")
list.forEach(function (lis) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = "Delete";
    lis.appendChild(button);
    ul.appendChild(lis);
});
```

}

Comment: You do not *append* the `btn` to any element. You just toss around `li` between `btn` and `ul`.

Comment: `button` elements cannot contain `li` elements, so `btn.appendChild(li)` doesn't make much sense. Also, `li` is not defined anywhere...

Comment: I just shared the function li is defined in the starting of the code li is a variable which grabs the li elements using the querySelectorAll method

Comment: Be aware that it will not work if `li` is a *NodeList* fetched by `querySelectorAll()` yet merely on single nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in the last lines

```
function createButton() {
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "Delete";
li.appendChild(btn);
ul.appendChild(li);

}
```

here is a simple example of how to add buttons to the list, you can extend on it and customise it

```html
<body>
  <ul id= "list" >
    
    </ul>
    <button onclick="createButton()">add delete buttons</button>

<script>
  
  const ul=document.getElementById("list")
  function createButton() {
  const btn = document.createElement("button")
  const li = document.createElement("li")
  const br = document.createElement("br")

  btn.textContent = "Delete"
  li.appendChild(btn);
  ul.appendChild(li); 
  ul.appendChild(br) 
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: tried this but still could not make it work shall I have to put the function in a loop to make it work?

Comment: can you post the html as well

Comment: there is no error in the console but when I inspected the elements the delete elements were not created

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working example check it out and let me know if it works for you

Comment: I have updated the question please check if you can help me